# Uniqueness of tense suffix *ood in Stood

Tags: etymology, tenses

Searching https://visca.com/regexdict/ for verbs like ".*and$" (ending in a n d), revealed some, but only those with the root "stand" have a past tense ending in o o d. Looking for verbs unrelated to "stand" that end in o o d revealed only "snood", which seems like it was a noun that got verbed in the present tense.

Is there something about the origin of "stand" which gave it this unique past tense suffix? And why don't other verbs have it?

Comment: Is  _".*and$"_ some linguistic nomenclature?

Comment: That syntax is a standard from computer science for matching text patterns called "regex". The website that I referenced uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stand is strong verb. [Strong verbs](https://people.umass.edu/sharris/in/gram/GrammarBook/StrongVerbs.html) are verbs in which the vowel in the stem is changed to indicate tense, person, and mood.

[Stand:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/stand?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_21995)

> (from Old English standan ) class VI strong verb; past tense stod, past participle standen. (Etymonline)

Another exemple is: to take/took.

Comment: The Middle English (https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED43062/track?counter=7&search_id=6196566) is probably more useful for "to stand" -> stonden v. (pronounced with a long "o" and probably later represented by "oo".) -- The spelling was never regular until c.18th century and represented the word phonetically. "Stood", as the simple past, seems to have developed from the possible pronunciations.